# Unity3d opening in background

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-8.1

When I start Unity5 (when I open Unity.exe) and select some project, for some reason It starts running in the background and the Editor window doesn't show up. When I check the Task Manager, Unity is running, but as I said it's in background and I can't see any window. It happens with all the projects I've tried. I'm trying now with a fresh install and it keeps happening. This happened previously with Unity 4.6 too.

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro.

My log: http://pastebin.com/aysjEjJG

What can be causing it?

Comment: Obvious question first, is it open off monitor (past edge of screen)?

Comment: No, it isn't, the window just don't opens.